# Get the Min and Max in a Linked Lists

Tags: java, list

I have made the following code, and I saw that Collection.max(list)is a way of finding the max in a linked list. It does not, however, recognizes the **Collection** part. How do I use it correctly?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class linkedlist {
 public static void main (String args[]) {
     LinkedList<Integer> fl = new LinkedList<Integer>();
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     fl.add((int)(Math.random() * (19) + 1));
     System.out.println(fl);
    int max = Collections.max(fl);
   }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: It does not recognize the Collections.max(fl);

Comment: Your example does not show the import for `Collections`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `import java.util.Collections;` that'l fix your code.
Avoid using the `sort` method since it runs at worse complexity (`O(nlogn)`) and alters the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list and get the element at 0 and size-1

```
Collections.sort(fl);
System.out.println(fl);
System.out.println(fl.get(0));
System.out.println(fl.get(fl.size() - 1));
```

but if you dont want to sort the list, and prefer to keep the insertion order, do

```
int max = Collections.max(fl);
Collections.sort(fl);
System.out.println(max);
int min = Collections.min(fl);
```

and dont forget to import the java.util.Collections;

Comment: This will change the list while we just want to extract a value from it. No need to change it.